# Product of random variable converges in mean

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $X_n \in \mathbb{R}$ converges in $L_p$ to $X \in \mathbb{R}$ i.e. $\mathbb{E}|X_n - X|^p \rightarrow 0$. Likewise $Y_n \in \mathbb{R}$ converges in $L_p$ to $Y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Is it true that $X_nY_n$ converges in $L_p$ to $XY$? I can show similar results for convergence in probability and almost sure convergence, but can't seem to find a proof for $L_p$ convergence.

Comment: Note that $X_nY_n$ is not necessarily in $L^p$. For example, $1/\sqrt x$ is in $L^1(0,1)$, but  its square isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but using Cauchy Schwarz, it holds that $\|AB\|_{p/2} \leq \|A\|_p\|B\|_p$, from which you can get $X_nY_n \to XY$ in $L^{p/2}$.

In a more general setting, if $X_n \to X$ in $L^p$ and $Y_n \to Y$ in $L^q$, then you have $X_nY_n \to XY$ in $L^r$, where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=\frac{1}{r}$. For this one may use Holder's inequality.